# How to run dockerfile in cmd

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

I am using Windows 10 machine and new to docker technology.

I prepared the Dockerfile.txt file and kept inside the DockerFiles folder in local system.

and executed the below command.

docker build -t my-r-image .

But it is not able to read.

Can anyone please help?

[image]

The name is also correct.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Dockerfile must be named "Dockerfile" not "Dockerfile.txt", no txt filename extension

Comment: I changed it to Dockerfile still getting the same error.

Comment: you can try to specify the Dockerfile in the command line using `-f Dockerfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `dockerfile` has the same name as the one shown in your terminal, example:

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount320670870/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

The `dockerfile` needs no extension, in Windows, you can create it with notepad++ and save it as "all types (.)"

You can try typing the full path of your dockerfile:

```
docker build -t X:X O:\Users\yyy\XX
```

Comment: Thanks alot...saving the Dockerfile in notepad++  worked !!